# Two types in QList

Tags: c++, arrays, list, qt5, qlist

I'm trying to return QList with two values in it, but each value should have different type.
First value in QString, second value in integer or short integer (up to 6 digits).

I have no idea where to start, can you help me with this please?

Comment: Then you shouldn't use `QList` if you think type elision is not your choice. Why not try to return a `QPair`?

Comment: ^^^ *or*... do you mean each element in the `QList` should contain a `QString` and a `short`?  In which case `QList<QPair<QString, short>>` might be appropriate.

Comment: `QList`, as many other containers, is [*homogeneous*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/homogeneous), i.e. they can only store values of a single type. If you want different types in a single list, then look into [`QVariant`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvariant.html) or [`std::any`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any).

Comment: You can use a list of QObject or QString then convert to integer or short integer when needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you realy need it as a list, I would simply use a QList of QPair.